# What does "making the play-offs" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The players who physically display their appreciation—through head raps,
>   bear hugs, and hip and chest bumps—inspire their teammates to play
>   better and win nearly two more games per season (which is both
>   statistically significant and often the difference between **making
>   the play-offs** and not).

I know the meaning of [play-off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/playoff):

> one of a series of games played after the regular season to decide
>   which teams will advance to play for the championship (= compete to be
>   recognized as the best team.)

but I can't understand the meaning of the phrase below:

> the difference between **making the play-offs** and not

So, could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[**make**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make)

> 6.3 Achieve a place in.
> *Australia should make the final*

"Make the play-offs" = "The team got enough points in the general classification to be included in the group that is going to dispute the play-offs"